# missing : after property id code was copied from a working example?

Tags: jquery, validation, properties

I copied this code and changed the final line "You must the fill in this field." from just "" (blank). The code worked in fine before (in the example) but now I get the error 'missing : after property id' on line one in this case. I checked to see if there was any vars I had missed or anything like that but no. Strange could really do with some help. I am using a jQuery plugin by the way.

I added more code as requested but I don't really think theres anything else I can add. I am using a plugin lib that I thought would be doing the rest. [See documentation here.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage)

```
    // a custom method making the default value for item and description invalid.
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("defaultInvalid", function(value, element) {
        return value != element.defaultValue;
    }, "You must the fill in this field.");

   rules: {
     item: {
       minlength: 3
     },
     desciption: {
       required: true,
       minlength: 3
     },
     city: {....................
```

Comment: This is definitely not enough information for any useful assistance.  Your error sounds like its referring to an attempt to parse an incorrectly defined JSON object, but the issue is almost certainly happening elsewhere.  Try to figure out the smallest code example that generates the error you're seeing, then post all of that code (but if it's not pretty small, few will read it carefully).

Comment: I've added more information but there isn't really a lot more I can add that really has context to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, my mistake. I had written the function after the form validate which is apparently incorrect. I had to play around to find this out. The online documentation didn't explain this. Code should be like the following:

```
     // a custom method making the default value for item and description invalid.
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("defaultInvalid", function(value, element) { 
        return value != element.defaultValue;
    }, "You must the fill in this field.");

$("#l_form").validate({

   rules: {
     item: {
       minlength: 3
     },
     desciption: {
       required: true,
       minlength: 3
     },....................
```